# regular k-gons that can tessellate a plane

Tags: geometry, contest-math, polygons, tessellations

> What is the sum of all possible values of $k$ for which regular $k-$gons can tessellate a plane?

This is one of the NAT problems. While I am familiar with tessellations, I don't quite get what they mean by tessellating a plane. Shouldn't all polygons be able to fill up a plane?

Comment: Uh ... 13, maybe?

Comment: Yes, that is the answer...

Comment: Now, try to fit a whole number of pentagons around a common vertex leaving no gaps at that vertex.  You can't.  Why?  What are the only regular polygons where you can do this without leaving any gaps?

Comment: Oh their angles don’t sum to 360 degrees and the only ones that work are the poloygons with angles that are factors of 360?

Comment: You hit the bull's eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $n$-gon has angle sum $(n-2)180^\circ$. If this $n$-gon is regular each of its angles therefore is ${n-2\over n}180^\circ$. Since we want that an integer number $k$ of such regular $n$-gons meet at each vertex of the tessellation we have to insist that ${n-2\over n}180^\circ={1\over k}360^\circ$, or
$$k={n\over n-2}\in{\mathbb N}\ .$$
Now try $n=3$, $4$, $5$, $\ldots$, and see in which cases the resulting $k$ is integer. You will obtain a finite list of admissible $n$s and then have to check for which of these $n$s a tessellation is indeed possible.

Comment: it's \frac{2n}{n-2}